# measure for deviation/error that is guarantueed to be smaller than the mean

Tags: data-visualization, standard-deviation, error, mean-absolute-deviation

I am presenting some non-negative values by using a mean value with error bars, basically something like this:

[image]

So the mean values are shown as dots and the error bars are displayed vertically, centered around the dots. This means that the value of the lower error bar is at `MEAN-ERROR` and the value of the upper error bar is at `MEAN+ERROR`.

A candidate for the error measure would be the standard deviation. However, this would make it possible that the lowest error bar is below zero (Since it is possible that `MEAN < STANDARD DEVIATION`), which might be counter-intuitive.

Is there some error measure which is guaranteed to be smaller than the mean value, and therefore never has error bars below zero?

Due to some external requirements, I can't use median/quartile based measurement. However, if needed, something directed (with a negative/positive error) can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you know that the true values of this unknown value must be greater than zero? This seems like the perfect time to incorporate a **prior**.

Let's call the random variable $X$. Since we know $X$ cannot be less than zero, you are correct in saying that reporting a value of $X$ as, for example, $X=0.23 \pm 0.44$, does not make much sense. I think in this case, it's perfectly acceptable to report the error as $X=0.23^{+0.44}_{-0.23}$. It's not under-reporting the error; it's incorporating real knowledge we have about the distribution we are studying.

There are a couple of other ways to approach this problem, too. Personally, I like looking for a $68\%$ (or $95\%$) confidence interval - but if your external requirements don't allow that, that's fine.

Another trick you can use is to transform your data into log-space first, then compute the mean and standard deviation of $\log(X)$ before transforming back. This will ensure that the upper- and lower- estimates of $X$ are both greater than zero, and it is the more sensible thing to do if it looks like your data follow a log-normal distribution.

To summarise, there are a lot of ways to solve this problem, including:

- Taking a Bayesian approach, and incorporating the knowledge that $X>0$;
- Using a robust error measurement method, such as a $68\%$ confidence interval;
- Transforming your data into log-space to ensure non-negativity.

I recommend looking into each of these methods in more detail, and deciding which one is best for the problem you have at hand. Have fun!

Comment: Great answer, this helps me a lot!